# Sitemap for Google

Tags: xml, sitemap

I have a website on which users can Ask Questions & Answer them as well. Means new content gets added every moment on website. **I don't know anything about sitemaps & I generated one using xml-sitemaps.com**. I have two question,

`First:` This is the basic structure of sitemap looks like,

```
<url>
    <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

Since new content is added every time on website, should I change the `changefreq` to `hourly` or `always`. Which would be better?

`Second:` In the sitemap I just created, there are dynamic urls. Means when user asks a new question It generates a new URL, something like `example.com/new-question/`. How new url will be added to the sitemap? Will I need to update the sitemap daily?

Please answer. Thank You in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `changefreq` of each URL should try to match the frequency of changes, as documented at https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html. Search engines may or may not use this tag, so don't expect that your site will be crawled daily through `<changefreq>daily</changefreq>`

For the second question: you could either let your application generate the XML file on accessing it or write your own crawler that collects al URLs of your site and write them to the sitemap.

Comment: Thank You very much. I've one more question :). In the auto generated sitemap there are several login redirect URLs, should I keep them as well?

Comment: Are they relevant? Do they contain information that should be indexed through a search engine?

Comment: For example there's a URL which pointing users to answer a question. But before answering a question they must be logged in. So, xml-sitemaps.com has automatically generated this `<loc>https://www.example.com/login/?next=my-question/9/</loc>`. Should I keep this URL as well? or should I completely block all the URLs requiring user login first in `robots.txt` file?

Comment: Does the linked page contain relevant information? It's up to you to decide that and either keep it or kick it

Comment: No, it doesn't contain any information. It just contains a form on which user can write answer. I'm thinking about keeping only those URLs which contains some useful content, along-with with few more important pages like Login & Register. Thank You very much for your guidance :)